# Selecting a directory from a list

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path

I have an issue when trying to get user input to select a directory obtained from a list

```
def  listPath():                                 
    p = list(os.listdir(work_path,))
    for dirs in enumerate(p,1):
       i = print(dirs, sep ="\n")
```

This outputs a numbered list of directories in the current folder:

```
(1, 'Folder 1')
(2, 'Folder 2')
(3, 'Folder 3')
```

I would like to allow the user to select a directory from this list and then move into that directory.
But I'm lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
answer = input("Which folder do you want,enter a number?")
```

to ask the user.  Then use what he inputs.

```
print("You selected folder: {}".format(p[int(answer)-1]))
```

Minus 1 because you added 1 in your enumerate.

Comment: I'm still playing around with this, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might be this:

```
def  listPath():
    path = 'your path'
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        print(x)     # this prints the folders or file that are inside your path directory
```

To get output in full path of the file or folder and to select the folder then you can do

```
 import os


 def listPath():

    list_path = []
    numbered = 1
    path = 'your path'

    for x in os.listdir(path):
        acutal_path = str(numbered) + ' ' + path + os.sep + x     #This variable stores full path for your all sub directory
        list_path.append(actual_path)
        print(str(numbered) + actual_path)

    answer = input("Which folder do you want,enter a number?")  # Ask user to enter to which number they want to enter

    for y in list_path:
        if answer in y:
            print('You have selected {}'.format(list_path[int(answer)])

    os.chdir(actual_path[int(answer)])    # Change you to the selected directory by the user.
```

Comment: I'm still playing around with this, thanks a lot for your help!